# Why is my Python to Qlik SSE plugin not working?

Tags: python, plugins, connection, qliksense

I have followed all the instructions from the following GitHub tutorial on the official Qlik GitHub (HelloWorld python example):
https://github.com/qlik-oss/server-side-extension/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld
https://github.com/qlik-oss/server-side-extension/blob/master/examples/python/GetStarted.md

However, I am struggling to get this to work.

I am using Qlik Sense Enterprise on the web and the latest version of Python.

When I run the **main**.py file I get a connection to the correct port, however when opening Qlik Sense and the .qvf app nothing is loaded, and the command prompt doesn't show the capabilities that should be listed.

I have setup certificates and they are in the right place and folder path has been set in the Analytical connection. Everything else I keep the same as the GitHub docs.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong and really need some help.

Steps taken:
(screenshots)

Certificates:
[image: Certificates:]

[image: Analytical connection:]

[image: Folder with all scripts in for HelloWorld:]

[image: Command prompt when I run python main.py:]

Result (or no result) to Qlik app:
[image: Result (or no result) to Qlik app:]

Environment:
Operating system - Windows
Qlik Sense - Enterprise Server (web)

Versions:
server-side-extension: One from the GitHub repo
Qlik Sense Enterprise: Most recent to the date posted

Comment: Not sure there's enough here to go off of tbh. Check the Python logs in the `logs` folder to see if things were set up correctly. Also make sure you chose the correct port for the example function you're testing out, it looks like there are several: https://github.com/qlik-oss/server-side-extension/blob/master/examples/python/GetStarted.md#running-the-python-examples

Comment: Also make sure that Qlik is actually recognizing the example script as a function: https://s3.arcanalytics.us/s3/public-assets/Screenshot%202022-12-03%20135840.png

Comment: @SmoothBrane Thanks for the reply. I get a log of when I run the script and it says:
'2022-12-06 10:20:11,024 - INFO - __main__ : 41 - Logging enabled
2022-12-06 10:20:11,047 - INFO - __main__ : 295 - *** Running server in insecure mode on port: 50053 ***'

The port seems to be right. Qlik isn't recognizing the script as a function:

The following error occurred:
'HelloWorld.EchoTable_3' is not a registered SSE function. Ensure the plugin is running and try restarting Qlik Engine.

Comment: @SmoothBrane Is it something to do with the host? I am using localhost atm.